# Getting AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'UniqueConstraint' in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, unique-constraint

I am using Django 1.11 and when trying to import `UniqueConstraint`, I am getting this terrible

> AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'UniqueConstraint'

error. I don't want to step down to unique_together, because it seems like being depreciated. So why I get this error in the latest version of Django ?!

I am importing it the following way:

```
from django.db import models

class CalendarAccount(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_table'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(...),
        ]
```

Comment: Isn't this was added only in Django [2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)?

Comment: But Django 1.11 is NOT the latest version of Django! In fact, it's only going to be supported until April 2020, see [the supported versions in the docs](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't exist yet if you're using django 1.11.

If you move to 2.2, use `UniqueConstraint`, but by then you'll have set `unique_together` and it isn't deprecated yet, so no point changing it.

Django 1.11 [docs for `unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

As a pointer, by looking at the available versions of the documentation in the bottom right, you can see if what you're reading is relevant to the version of django you are using.

The [docs for `UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) show only 2.2, 3.0 and dev so that isn't available prior to 2.2.

Anyway, docs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together